# FileAlreadyExistsException with REPLACE_EXISTING option

Tags: java, file, exception, move

Inside my code there is a loop to substitute a file with another file.

This is done with:

```
java.nio.file.Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options) throws IOException
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\BRUTE-FORCE\Test-Loads-2-forces-only.dat.temp -> C:\BRUTE-FORCE\Test-Loads-2-forces-only.dat
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
(*) at bruteforce.Main.changeValue(Main.java:260)
    at bruteforce.Main.main(Main.java:71)
```

The line at which the exception is thrown:

```
(*) at bruteforce.Main.changeValue(Main.java:260):

Files.move(path, path.resolveSibling("DESTINY_FILE"), REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Javadoc defines the exception:

```
...
FileAlreadyExistsException - if the target file exists but cannot be replaced because the REPLACE_EXISTING option is not specified (optional specific exception) 
...
```

The code clearly specifies REPLACE_EXISTING.

Also the option is imported at the beginning of the file:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
```

Any hint?

It could be due to the computer (or the HDD) hybernates or something similar?
I have set the enegy options not suspends while using the power grid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you can't have that error. You call `path.resolveSibling("DESTINY_FILE")` but there is no `DESTINY_FILE` is your error message...

Comment: maybe you could debug, try to log `Files.isWritable(path)` a line above you error... maybe you forgot to close your resource earlier (just speculating)

Comment: We are experiencing the same problem and I can reproduce it with a tiny program writing and then moving a file in a loop. Works fine on Linux. Workaround seems to be to delete an existing destination file before Files.move().

Comment: Funnily enough, we have the exact same workaround somewhere in our code, written years before this post, with a comment saying that they only ever saw it on Windows.

Comment: I saw this error while attempting to write to same file from multiple threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files.move is not an atomic operation (unless of course ATOMIC_MOVE is specified), so what i assume is happenig some other IO got lock on this file.

Please make sure you:

- Lunch `close()` method on this resource or use *try-with-resources*
- Your OS is not using this file (eg. opened in Notepad, you lunch
  *tail* against it)

If you file is often accesed, then you can try to create loop  that checks  `Files.isWritable()`